# Mongo aggregate lookup nested

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am struggling to achieve a nested response to a notes nested based schema. I use document parent field to assign child comments (replies) to parent documents.

I also need to do an internal lookup to get the user data which is also store on the document (this is my challenge)

Notes documents:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("629e0a84e0229e4fba0de395"), 
    "order" : ObjectId("6298b2a563edd8c9cfa47ba2"), 
    "notes" : "Aut pariatur Volupt", 
    "createdBy" : ObjectId("61c2abdff3edde4ab0074ca9"),  
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("629ea872a89b4d1464451307"), 
    "order" : ObjectId("6298b2a563edd8c9cfa47ba2"), 
    "notes" : "dewdewdwe", 
    "createdBy" : ObjectId("61c2abdff3edde4ab0074ca9"), 
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("629f578460c133c4aab8c028"), 
    "order" : ObjectId("6298b2a563edd8c9cfa47ba2"), 
    "notes" : "dewdwe", 
    "createdBy" : ObjectId("61c2abdff3edde4ab0074ca9"), 
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("62a000865f24e1887dfd169e"), 
    "order" : ObjectId("6298b2a563edd8c9cfa47ba2"), 
    "noteParent" : ObjectId("629e0a84e0229e4fba0de395"), 
    "notes" : "Yes this one is ok", 
    "createdBy" : ObjectId("619e13eeabdf5bf20384b74a"), 
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("62a004d1a3c340725d0c732b"), 
    "order" : ObjectId("6298b2a563edd8c9cfa47ba2"), 
    "noteParent" : ObjectId("629e0a84e0229e4fba0de395"), 
    "notes" : "this one too", 
    "createdBy" : ObjectId("619e13eeabdf5bf20384b74a"), 
}
```

**noteParent** is a child of other documents
**createdBy** needs a lookup to the **users** collection

With the following aggregate I get the correct nested documents.

```
db.getCollection("ordernotes").aggregate(
    [
        { 
            "$lookup" : { 
                "from" : "users", 
                "localField" : "createdBy", 
                "foreignField" : "_id", 
                "as" : "createdBy"
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$lookup" : { 
                "from" : "ordernotes", 
                "localField" : "_id", 
                "foreignField" : "noteParent", 
                "as" : "replies"
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$project" : { 
                "order" : 1.0, 
                "notes" : 1.0, 
                "status" : 1.0, 
                "replies" : 1.0, 
                "createdByModel" : 1.0, 
                "createdBy.firstName" : 1.0, 
                "createdBy.lastName" : 1.0, 
                "createdBy.email" : 1.0, 
            }
        }
    ], 
);
```

However, how can do a another lookup on **replies.createdBy** without overriding the ***replies*** nested document

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("629e0a84e0229e4fba0de395"), 
    "order" : ObjectId("6298b2a563edd8c9cfa47ba2"), 
    "notes" : "Aut pariatur Volupt", 
    "status" : "pending", 
    "createdBy" : [
        {
            "firstName" : "Jim", 
            "lastName" : "Jones", 
            "email" : "xxxx7@gmail.com", 
        }
    ], 
    "replies" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("62a000865f24e1887dfd169e"), 
            "order" : ObjectId("6298b2a563edd8c9cfa47ba2"), 
            "noteParent" : ObjectId("629e0a84e0229e4fba0de395"), 
            "notes" : "Yes this one is ok", 
            "createdBy" : ObjectId("619e13eeabdf5bf20384b74a"), 
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("62a004d1a3c340725d0c732b"), 
            "order" : ObjectId("6298b2a563edd8c9cfa47ba2"), 
            "noteParent" : ObjectId("629e0a84e0229e4fba0de395"), 
            "notes" : "this one too", 
            "createdBy" : ObjectId("619e13eeabdf5bf20384b74b"), 
        }
    ]
}
```

Expected output:

```
    "_id" : ObjectId("629e0a84e0229e4fba0de395"), 
    "order" : ObjectId("6298b2a563edd8c9cfa47ba2"), 
    "notes" : "Aut pariatur Volupt", 
    "status" : "pending", 
    "createdBy" : [
        {
            "firstName" : "Jim", 
            "lastName" : "Jones", 
            "email" : "xxxx7@gmail.com", 
        }
    ], 
    "replies" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("62a000865f24e1887dfd169e"), 
            "order" : ObjectId("6298b2a563edd8c9cfa47ba2"), 
            "noteParent" : ObjectId("629e0a84e0229e4fba0de395"), 
            "notes" : "Yes this one is ok", 
            "createdBy" : [
            {
                "firstName" : "Jane", 
                "lastName" : "Doe", 
                "email" : "dnjkwndjkew@gmail.com", 
            }
            ] 
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("62a004d1a3c340725d0c732b"), 
            "order" : ObjectId("6298b2a563edd8c9cfa47ba2"), 
            "noteParent" : ObjectId("629e0a84e0229e4fba0de395"), 
            "notes" : "this one too", 
            "createdBy" : [
            {
                "firstName" : "Bob", 
                "lastName" : "Carr", 
                "email" : "bobcarr@gmail.com", 
            }
           ] , 
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please show your expected output

Comment: The question is unclear, other lookup on which collection? Please provide the other collection which you wand to add in, and the expected output

Comment: sorry - i've just added the expected output to assist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want something like this:

1. `$lookup` into a new array `repliesNotes`
2. `$map` to merge each object on `replies` with its matching object on `repliesNotes`

```
db.notes.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "replies.createdBy",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "repliesNotes"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      replies: {
        $map: {
          input: "$replies",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {
                createdBy: {
                  $arrayElemAt: [
                    "$repliesNotes",
                    {$indexOfArray: ["$repliesNotes._id", "$$this.id"]}
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      repliesNotes: "$$REMOVE"
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wGiPAw7CCun)

Comment: Perfect! I am not familiar with $set ... will need to conduct more research to understand it. Thanks!